# Button doesn't appear on window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ErrorControl Class that handles a text being sent to this control, and displays it in a window. Along with the text in the window, I have a btnOk that should display. So a window with just a label and a button. The label with the error displays fine, but the button does not show.

code behind:

```
        public void showErrorMessage(String error, String title)
    {
        ErrorControl errorMessage = new ErrorControl();
        errorMessage.errStack.Children.Remove(errorMessage.lblError);
        errorMessage.lblError.Content = error.ToString();
        errorMessage.errStack.Children.Add(errorMessage.lblError);
        Window wind = new Window()
        {
            Content = error,
            Title = title,
            SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow
        };

        wind.ShowDialog();
    }
```

xaml:

```
    <Grid Name="Main">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Name="errStack">
        <Label Name="lblError" Content="{Binding Path=ErrorMessage}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Name="btnOk" Content="Ok" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="75" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="btnOk_Click"/>

</Grid>

</Grid>
```

and this is how I am sending the error

```
                    String error = "myerror";
                ErrorControl errorControl = new ErrorControl();
                errorControl.showErrorMessage(error, "Error Message");
```

why is my button not appearing in my window? it is defined in my xaml.

Comment: Why are you declaring `errorControl` twice?  There is nothing linking `Label Name="lblError"` to  `errorMessage.lblError`

Comment: I am calling error control first in one of my seperate files, Class.cs, then I am calling errorcontrol again in my ErrorControl file. The label is working fine though, the button is what is not being displayed on the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you assign the error text instead the ErrorControl to `Window.Content`.

Corrected:

```
Window wind = new Window()
{
    Content = errorMessage, // << your problem is here
    Title = title,
    SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow
};
```

Also I want to add that your code has design problems. `showErrorMessage` should be at least static so you don't have to create an ErrorControl and just call

```
ErrorControl.showErrorMessage(error, "Error Message");
```

Comment: Thank you for that fix! it worked, I also changed my code to work in the design way which you mentioned. I have 1 question though, why does the Content need errorControl in this situation. I am just trying to learn. thanks

Comment: Because you want to see your button, or? Assigning a string instead of your control to content will ofcourse not show you your button which resides inside your ErrorControl but some default handling for strings.